# ORACLE PL/SQL Function is created successfully but the execution body is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

These are the list of tables I have created and inserted values for the created tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
 );

 CREATE TABLE JOBS
 (JOB_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  JOB_TITLE VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  MIN_SALARY DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  MAX_SALARY DECIMAL NOT NULL
  );

 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
(EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 EMAIL VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
 JOB_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
 SALARY DECIMAL NOT NULL,
 DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT emp_job_fk FOREIGN KEY(JOB_ID) REFERENCES JOBS(JOB_ID),
 CONSTRAINT emp_department_fk FOREIGN KEY(DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_ID)
 );

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME)
VALUES(1,'IT');
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME)
VALUES(2,'Sales');

INSERT INTO JOBS (JOB_ID,JOB_TITLE,MIN_SALARY,MAX_SALARY)
VALUES (1,'IT Administrator',250000.00,50000.00);
INSERT INTO JOBS (JOB_ID,JOB_TITLE,MIN_SALARY,MAX_SALARY)
VALUES (2,'Salesman',200000.00,40000.00);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (1,'Tony','Starc','starc@gmail.com','0123456789',TO_DATE('15/1/2008','DD/MM/YYYY'),1,45000.00,1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (2,'Bruce','Wayne','bruce@gmail.com','0123456788',TO_DATE('15/1/2009','DD/MM/YYYY'),1,40000.00,1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (3,'Larry','Ellison','larry@gmail.com','0123456787',TO_DATE('15/1/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'),1,30000.00,1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (4,'Steve','Jobs','steve@gmail.com','0123456786',TO_DATE('15/1/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'),2,35000.00,2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (5,'Remy','Lebeau','remy@gmail.com','0123456785',TO_DATE('15/1/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'),2,30000.00,2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (6,'Clark','Kent','clark@gmail.com','0123456784',TO_DATE('15/1/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'),2,35000.00,2);
```

Now in my assignment question, I have been asked to solve the following question: 
**Write a function called fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912 to retrieve EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME AND JOB_TITLE with a given DEPARTMENT_ID. This function should have DEPARTMENT_ID as input parameter and this function should have EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME AND JOB_TITLE as output parameters. It should return TRUE if found and FALSE if not found.**

In order to display the information of employees from a particular department, I have written the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912 (f_dept_id IN NUMBER,f_emp_id OUT NUMBER,f_first_name OUT VARCHAR,f_last_name OUT VARCHAR,f_job_title OUT VARCHAR)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
BEGIN
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,JOB_TITLE
INTO f_emp_id,f_first_name,f_last_name,f_job_title
FROM EMPLOYEES,JOBS,DEPARTMENT
WHERE DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
AND JOBS.JOB_ID = EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID
AND EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = f_dept_id;
RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee not found');
RETURN FALSE;
END fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912;

Function FN_EMPS_PER_DEPT_JC450912 compiled
```

As you can see from the above that the function has been successfully compiled.

Then I tried executing the function:

```
DECLARE
f_dept_id NUMBER;
f_emp_id NUMBER;
f_first_name VARCHAR(30) ;
f_last_name VARCHAR(30) ;
f_job_title VARCHAR(30);
f_return BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
f_dept_id := 1;
f_return := fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912(f_dept_id,f_emp_id,f_first_name,f_last_name,f_job_title);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee_ID: ' || f_emp_id);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First Name: ' || f_first_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last Name: ' || f_last_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job: ' || f_job_title);
END;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.FN_EMPS_PER_DEPT_JC450912", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 10
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

I need the solution code for the execution body to fix this error.

Comment: Your last insert `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE ...... TO_DATE('15/1/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')` is incomplete, it causes parsing error `SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma`

Comment: I have already edited and fixed that. But, I am looking for solution code for the execution body. That's the only thing I need to fix. The function is successfully created. But, I'm stuck with the execution syntax. Would be helpful if you can provide the solution code for the execution part.

Comment: Actually you haven't fixed it all - Superman is still missing a Job_ID, salary and department_id

Comment: Software testing doesn't stop at a successful compilation. What you have discovered is a [runtime error](https://techterms.com/definition/runtime_error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly please use modern join syntax (ANSI standard since 92!).

So your SELECT should be:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,JOB_TITLE
INTO f_emp_id,f_first_name,f_last_name,f_job_title
FROM EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN JOBS ON JOBS.JOB_ID = EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = f_dept_id;
```

Next when you get a problem like this, you should just run the query in a query window, like this:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,JOB_TITLE
FROM EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN JOBS ON JOBS.JOB_ID = EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1;
```

This will reveal the cause of your problem as the output looks like this

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 JOB_TITLE                         
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- -----------------------------------
          1 Tony                 Starc                     IT Administrator                   
          2 Bruce                Wayne                     IT Administrator                   
          3 Larry                Ellison                   IT Administrator
```

I.e the field employees.department_id is not unique.  Therefore on execution the stored procedure is trying to put multiple values in a single variable.  This it cannot do, hence the error.  The procedure compiles ok, because at compile time, the procedure can have no idea that it will be passed a parameter which results in more than one record in the result set.

Comment: I have re-edited and added job id and salary for clark kent (superman). On the other hand, the assignment question demands me to create a function with department id as input parameter and other selected columns as output parameter. I'm just stuck in the execution part. It would be really helpful if you can provide the solution for the execution part only.

Comment: Please read my answer.  Given your data there can be no solution.  My best guess is that you have your assignment wrong.  Either the input parameter should be employee_id (not department_id) or you are expected to have a single output parameter which is a recordset (using sys_refcursor).

Comment: I have erased department id and included employee id as the input parameter and then I applied my function execution logic it worked and I'm getting the result by entering a valid employee id number and getting error while entering invalid employee id. When I'm using employee id as input parameter it is working perfectly. But, when I'm putting department id as input parameter to get employee details then it is showing error. It is not supposed to because I have already specified EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = f_dept_id  .  So that is strange for me.

Comment: @learningIT Department_ID is not unique in table employees.  It is a foreign key to Department, where it is unique.  Specifying where employees.department_id = f_dept_id does not therefore produce a single result set.  Hence your error.  How much plainer can I make this?

Comment: My pleasure.  Please mark the question as answered, by clicking the tick next to the answer.  It should turn green!